S/MIME certificates + mobile Outlooks + can't verify Signature
we bought S/MIME email certificates from a TRUSTED ISSUER. Everything works fine on almost all email clients like Outlook 365 for Windows, Mozilla Thunderbird (even gmail web interface) except for mobile Outlooks (both Android and IOS). Mobile Outlooks show an alert that "can't verify Signature".
However after googling, I imported our issuer CA-certificate to our Office 365 instance (tenant) , using Powershell  command line:
Set-SmimeConfig -SMIMECertificateIssuingCA ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('C:\Users\ad....\our_trusted_issuer_certs.sst'))
Then it started to work fine on mobile Outlooks too (both Android and IOS), but only  within our Exchange Online 365 instance (only inside our organization/domain/tenant).
So external customers/users, who use mobile Outlooks still have this alert (can't verify Signature).
For obvious reasons it's impossible to ask external customers to import our issuer's CA-certificate to their Exchange instances...
So, can someone tell me if it's possible to configure it so that external clients with mobile Outlooks will recognize our signed emails as signed correctly ?
It looks like Outlooks on mobile devices don't use the system certificate store and that's why they don't recognize our emails as trusted/verified.
thank you for any advice or hint
